# How can I adjust my program to close the loop and print the expected results?

Tags: for-loop, salesforce, infinite-loop, apex

This is the error I'm getting. I believe this means its caught in an infinite loop:

> Line: 2, Column: 1
>   System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded

The code below is what I've tried so far.

```
for(integer i = 7; i <= 15; i + 2){
    System.debug(i);
}
```

I expect it to print the following: 
7 
9 
11 
13 
15

Instead it is getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your diagnosis is correct; your code is caught in an infinite loop.

This is the case because of the third clause of your `for` loop:

```
for(integer i = 7; i <= 15; i + 2){
```

`i + 2` is an expression, but it doesn't change the value of `i`. You want to do `i += 2` here. See [Apex Operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm) for the details.